# Encryption with rotate amount and direction in Java

Tags: java

I have a program that I created awhile back that takes a string from a user and encrypts it. I am working on a second version of the program that takes a text file from the user, has the user enter a value for the shift, have the user enter the direction of the shift (left or right) and then outputs the encrypted message to a new file.

I have the program working now thanks to some help from other members, however it is not the way I want it. Now it takes the file and encrypts to a file, but is not using the shift or direction. If the user chooses a shift of 3 for example and a direction of right, the program should read the first letter of the text file and rotate the key array 3 spaces and print the character. Then the program looks at the next letter, rotates the array to the right 3 more spaces, and prints that character. I am really confused how I would the array to shift direction. I know I need to send the method doing the encryption the string created from the file, the shift direction, and the shift amount, then use a loop to go through and complete everything, but this is a little above my comprehension. Any help with the process would be greatly appreciated! Sorry for the long code but I want you to be able to see everything that's happening.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CaeserCipher {

  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

        String originalText="";
        String inputFile;
        String outputFile = "";
        String shiftDirection;
        int shiftValue;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt user for input file name
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("What is the filename?: ");
       inputFile = in.nextLine();


       //make sure file does not exist
            File file = new File(inputFile);
               if (!file.exists())
               {
                  System.out.println("\nFile " + inputFile + " does not exist. File could not be opened.");

                  System.exit(0);
               }

         //send the filename to be read into String

         originalText = readFile(inputFile);


         //Prompt user for shift value
         System.out.print("\nWhat is the shift value? ");
         shiftValue = keyboard.nextInt();

         //Prompt user for shift direction
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("What direction would you like to shift? Press L for left or R for right: ");

         //validate the input
         while (!sc.hasNext("[LR]")) {
             System.out.println("That's not a valid form of input! Please enter only the letter 'L' or 'R': ");
             sc.next();
             shiftDirection = sc.next(); //stores the validated direction
         }//end while

         shiftDirection = sc.next(); //stores the validated direction

         //Return encrypted string
         String encryptedText = encrypt(originalText , shiftValue);

         //get the outputfile name
         System.out.print("What is the name of the output file you want to create?: ");
         outputFile = in.nextLine();

         //make sure file does not exist
         File file2 = new File(outputFile);
            if (file2.exists())
            {
               System.out.println("\nFile " + outputFile + " already exists. Output not written.");

               System.exit(0);
            }

        try {
            File file3 = new File(outputFile);
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file3));
            output.write(encryptedText);
            output.close();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("\nOutput written to " + outputFile);        

    } //end main

    //rotate and change chars
    public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue) {

        String convertedText = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++){
        char lowerLetter = userString.charAt(i);

        //Convert to uppercase
        char upperLetter = Character.toUpperCase(lowerLetter);
        int charNumber = upperLetter;

        //Apply shift, remembering to wrap text
        int rotateShift = ((charNumber - 'A' + shiftValue) % 26) + 'A';
        char shiftLetter = (char) rotateShift;

        //Create new string of shifted chars
        convertedText += shiftLetter;
        }
      return convertedText;
    }

    //encrypt
    public static String encrypt(String userString, int shiftValue) {
        String encryptedString = rotate(userString , shiftValue);
        return encryptedString;
    }

    private static String readFile(String inputFile) throws java.io.IOException {
      File file = new File(inputFile);
      StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int) file.length());
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));
      String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

         try {
             if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                 fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine());
             }
             while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                 fileContents.append(lineSeparator + scanner.nextLine());
             }

         return fileContents.toString();
    }


     finally {
        scanner.close();
    }

 }
}
```

And here is the previous method I was using to encrypt just a string with no user input for shift amount or direction:

```
public static String doEncryption(String s)
    {
        char alphabet[]  = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
            'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
            'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };   //hold the characters in alphabet array
        char key[] = { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
            'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
            'x', 'y', 'z', 'a' };   //holds characters in the key array

        char encoded[] = new char[(s.length())];
        String encrypted="";  //initialize the string for the new message
        int j=0;     //count variable
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){  //begin for loop to run through string
            boolean isFound = false;
            j = 0;
            while (j < alphabet.length && !isFound){


                if (alphabet[j]==s.charAt(i)){
                   encrypted=encrypted+key[j];
                   isFound=true;
                }
                j++; 
            }
}
```

Could anyone help me understand what I need to do to rotate the array each time it gets to a new letter in the file? Thanks!

Comment: Small note -- in Java, arrays are typically declared as `type[] name`, not, `type name[]`. Neither will throw an error, but the former is more standard Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ArrayList<String>` instead of `char[]`. Replace `key[j]` with `key.get(j)`. Rotate the `ArrayList` by using a for loop and invoking `String s = key.remove(0)` and `key.add(s)`.

Comment: You mean `key.get(j)` -- the square brackets will throw an error.

Comment: Could you explain that a little bit? What exactly is `String s = key.remove(0)` and `key.add(s)` doing? If I use the `ArrayList<String>` instead of the char array, do I still have to initialize all the characters of the alphabet and does it take care of both arrays? Thanks for your time!

Comment: You would initialize the `ArrayList<String>`, convert the `char[]` to `String[]` and then use `Arrays.asList(String[])`. That will give you a `List<String>`. Use the `ArrayList.addAll(Collection<String>)` method to get an `ArrayList`. `ArrayList.remove(0)` will remove and return the first element in the `ArrayList`, which if you type parameterize it as `ArrayList<String>` will return a `String`. Then you just add the `String` you just removed to the back of the `ArrayList` - that should be a rotation.

Comment: This is way over my head lol. Do really appreciate your help and will look into that. Was really hoping I could just add the arrays to the first set of code I posted (inside the rotate method), change the method to accept the direction (which I'm still unsure how that works). Is there any simple way using the code I already have? Thank you @M.Shaw

Comment: I am just getting started in Java so I do apologize for my lack of knowledge on the subject!

Comment: You can duplicate the array, and then `for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { key[i] = duplicate[(i + shift) % 26]; }.